# How to override JWT token clocks for tests in Quarkus

Tags: unit-testing, jwt, quarkus

I would like to test how tokens behave and verified in future instants of time. For this I made custom `io.jsonwebtoken.Clock` which I wish to set at some fixed clocks during tests.

How to inject this class in the process of token verification?